# Handling page OnLoad using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In the below code, i am able to get the relevant content on clicking the header. But the problem is, on page load i am seeing all the headers and contents, only after clicking any header, the other contents are disappearing. That should not be the case.

On page load i should see only the Headers...How ?

```
<span>Click a Header!</span>
<div><h2>Sub Header 1</h2></div><div>Content 1</div>
<div><h2>Sub Header 2</h2></div><div>Content 2</div>
<div><h2>Sub Header 3</h2></div><div>Content 3</div>

<script language="javascript">

      $("h2").click(function () 
      {
          $("h2").not(this).parent().next().hide();
          $(this).parent().next().show();
      }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hide the content in the page load.Try with this following. It may be useful to you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("h2").parent().next().hide();  
});
$("h2").click(function (){
 $("h2").not(this).parent().next().hide();
 $(this).parent().next().show();
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

It's quite possible that your code, as it's written, will run before the DOM has loaded. The typical approach is to wrap it in `$(document).ready()` The `.ready` event is used to specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("h2").click(function () 
      {
          $("h2").not(this).parent().next().hide();
          $(this).parent().next().show();
      }); 
}
```

I would recommend checking out jQuery's [excellent documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for a more indepth explanation.

If you're seeing content that you expect to be hidden on load, you need to style it with `display:none`

Give the divs you don't want displayed a class (say, `hideOnLoad`) and either set the visibility attribute in the CSS or using jquery on load.

e.g.

```
$('.hideOnLoad').hide();
```

Comment: You have to use `display:none`, not `visibilty:hidden` (jQuery's `show()` and `.hide()` change the value of `display`, not `visibility`)

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest a slightly different markup, things get much easier (you won't need `.not(this).parent().next()` anymore):

```
<span>Click a Header!</span>
<div><h2>Sub Header 1</h2><div class="content">Content 1</div></div>
<div><h2>Sub Header 2</h2><div class="content">Content 2</div></div>
<div><h2>Sub Header 3</h2><div class="content">Content 3</div></div>
```

And the javascript, that could be right below the markup as you have it, or on document.ready (recommended):

```
$('.content').hide();
$('h2').click(function(){
   $('.content').hide(); 
   $(this).next('.content').show();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k2g8g/